# NAIP Google Earth Engine imageCollection Without Cloud Cover

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to gather an imageCollection of an 18 month period of Richmond, California.

Problem 1: extent not working
Problem 2: `print()` not working

Below is my attempted code that is not working.

```
// create NAIP image collection within time frame and extent
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NAIP/DOQQ')

.filter(ee.Filter.date('2017-03-01', '2019-06-15'));                .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(-122.35107642463032,37.930370885512346));

// make it so the image is original                  
var trueColor = dataset.select(['R', 'G', 'B']);
var trueColorVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 255.0,
};
Map.addLayer(trueColor, trueColorVis, 'True Color');

//the information about collection should come up in the console

print(dataset);
```

Comment: Are there any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

For the region that you have specified, the NAIP dataset does not have any images in the date range that you want. If you remove the date range filter, there are 7 images for your point.

If you check the dates of the available images without using the date filter

```
var dates = ee.List(dataset.aggregate_array('system:time_start'));
dates = dates.map(function(number){
  return ee.Date(number);
})
print(dates)
```

You'll see that the latest image was of the date 2016-05-31. So your filter of 2017 to 2019 will give no images.